# How to under the "not the thing" part?

Tags: comparisons

The original text:

> A gentleman is, rather than does. He is interested in nothing in a
>   professional way. He is allowed to cultivate hobbies, even
>   eccentricities, but must not practise a vocation. He must know how to
>   ride and shoot and cast a fly. He should have relatives in the army
>   and navy and at least one connection in the diplomatic service. But
>   there are weaknesses in the English gentleman’s ability to rule us
>   today. He usually knows nothing of political economy and less about
>   how foreign countries are governed. He does not respect learning and
>   prefers ’sport ’. The problem set for society is not the virtues of
>   the type so much as its adequacy for its function, and here grave
>   difficulties arise. **He refuses to consider sufficiently the wants of
>   the customer, who must buy, not the thing he desires but the thing the
>   English gentleman wants to sell**.

My question are about the last sentence. I've numerated my questions as below.

> **He[1]** refuses to consider sufficiently the wants of the customer, **who must buy[2]**, **not the thing [3] he[4]** desires but the thing the English gentleman wants to sell.

[1] **He** refers to **the gentleman**, right?

[2] "**who must buy**" is the non-restrictive clause for "**the customer**"

[4] "**he**" refers to "**the customer**" here.

[3] How is "**not the thing he desires**" related to other parts in the sentence (ignoring the parallel "**but the thing.**.." part afterwards)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers to [1], [2] and [4] are correct.

**Not A but B** describes what the customer 'must buy' - not what he wants but what the 'gentleman' wants to sell to him.